# UIAnimation seems to be not working effectively

Tags: iphone, ipad, uianimation

i'm using some simple UIAnimation properties to show and hide a UIView. This code seems to work perfectly for the very first time. But after that the animation effect is not being seen. is there anything im doing wrong in this code.. Im posting my code here.. Please correct me if my code is incorrect and please suggest me a correct approach. Thank you.

```
-(IBAction)animateSingleTap:(UIButton*)sender{
NSLog(@"trying to animate singletap");

    if(singleTapViewIsShowing==NO){

    [searchController hideSelf];
    [singleTapView sendSubviewToBack:hideSingleTapButton ];
    hideSingleTapButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"single tap animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut forView:singleTapView cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:singleTapView];
    hideSingleTapButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:singleTapView];
    optionsButton.selected=YES;
    singleTapViewIsShowing=YES;
    singleTapView.frame=CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x-95, sender.frame.origin.y+30, singleTapView.frame.size.width, singleTapView.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

else {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"single tap animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut forView:singleTapView cache:YES];
    [singleTapView removeFromSuperview];
    optionsButton.selected=NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    singleTapViewIsShowing=NO;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the animation works the first time but subsequently doesn't run.  Are you setting your sigleTapViewIsShowing to NO anywhere else in your code?  Of you're not the animation will trigger for the first time and execute...

```
singleTapViewIsShowing=YES;
```

This will stop any the animation running until you reset this flag elsewhere.  Are you?

Comment: @ mmccomb: thanku for ur answer bro.. i have edited my code and posted the full code snippet.. infact i'm setting singleTapViewIsShowing=NO in my code... Please have a look at my code... i have checked my code by putting some breakpoints in this method.. The control is entering here, but the animation effect is not being seen...

Comment: Try changing `[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut forView:singleTapView cache:YES];` to `[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut forView:self.view cache:YES];` in both animation blocks

Comment: @ mmccomb: hey bro.. i'v changed my strategy here... I have decided to use alpha property in the code snippet and it worked for me. I am setting singleTapView.alpha=1 and then changing it back to 0 and it worked for me. Thank you for your help. cheers...